# Microservice deployed - initial data migration

Tags: microservices

Let's say that we have microservice A (MS A) and Microservice B (MS B).
MS B has data about Products. MS A needs the productnames of MS B.

Each time a product is added, updated or deleted, MS B puts a message on a message queue.
MS A is subscribed to that queue, so it can updated it's own internal state.

Now my question:
How do we fill the internal state of MS A when we deploy it to production the first time?
I couldn't find any documentation about the pros and cons of the possible solutions.
I could think of:

1. Export/import on database level.

   Pros: not much work.

   Cons: can miss data if during export/import changes to the data of MS A are made.
2. Implement calls for GetData and GetDataChangedSince

   Pros: failsafe

   Cons: a lot of work

Are there any other options? Are there any other pros/cons?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following workflow:

- prepare the microservice B to push the events to the queue or stop it if it is already pushing to the queue; instead, it **pushes to a circular buffer** (a buffer that is rewritten when full) and waits for a signal from microservice A
- deploy the microservice A into production servers but you don't reference it from nowhere; it just runs, waiting for events in the queue
- run a script that get all product names from microservice B and push them into the queue as a simulated event; when it finishes the product names it signals the microservice B (optionally telling the date or sequence number or whatever de-duplication technique you have to detect duplicate events)
- microservice B then copy the events from the buffer newer that the last pushed by microservice A (or it finds out itself from the queue what is the last one) into the queue and then ignores the buffer and continue to work as normally.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is a service/API call  missing from you architecture. Moving a service into production should be no different than recovering from a a failure and should not require any additional steps. Perhaps the messages should be consumed from the queue by another service that can then be queried for the complete list of products.